# How do you take the first and second derivative of a summation with two variables?

Tags: summation, logarithms, exponential-function, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I want to prove that $log(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{x_i}})$ is convex. To do that I would need to find its gradient and Hessian, but I'm not sure how to take derivatives of summations with two variables.

EDIT: I was mistaken and there is only one variable $x$. I believe the first derivative would thus be, $\frac{d}{dx}$ $log(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{x_i}})$ = $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{x_i}}}$. Is this correct? Also, from there, how would I take the derivative of a summation of one variable to get the second derivative?

Comment: Ther is only summation with one variable, isn't there? $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f_i(x)$

Comment: Oh I see. I was confused by the $n$. I'll try and see what I get now.

Comment: for derivative of log you need to derivate the sum too $ \ \dot{ log(f(x))} = \frac  {f'(x)} { f(x) } $

Comment: Would $f'(x)$ be $ne^{x}$ in this case if $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{xi}}$?

Comment: now here $ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{xi}}$ so f'(x) is the derivative of each term of the serie of f(x)... it's a serie too

Comment: I wrote down the problem incorrectly. Could you check my edit?

Comment: @dirtysocks45, it looks like you have some multivariate calculus prerequisites to master. If you happen to be looking at the book _Convex Optimization_ by Boyd & Vandenberghe, check out Appendix A, "Mathematical Background". Most of that material should be a review. If it's not, you might get by just by learning the material there, but it will be tougher.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Do you think Apostol's *Calculus* would be a good book to look through?

Comment: I'm afraid I am unfamiliar with the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \log \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right)=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right) = \frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}}.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k^2}\log \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right)=\frac{e^{x_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}-e^{x_k}\right)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right)^2},$$ 
and
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k \partial x_j}\log \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right)=-\frac{e^{x_k}e^{x_j}}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right)^2},$$ where $j \neq k$, and $1 \le j,k \le n$.

Comment: Is there a way to take the derivative of the whole function instead of partial derivatives over the entire summation?

Comment: I get that now, but what about taking the derivative of the whole function?

Comment: What do you mean by the derivative of the whole function? I believe you meant the gradient. If that is the case, then it is just a vector of the partial derivatives.

Comment: @mathlover correct the indice of the exponential in the last expressin. The indice i is not needed...and it shoulkd be a serie at the numerator..

Comment: @Isham Why? Isn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \left(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2}\right) = e^{x_1}$?

Comment: Oh I see now. I forgot that the gradient could be a vector. Would the Hessian be a matrix of ones in this case because the second derivative is 1?

Comment: I believe that$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}\right) = \frac{ne^{x}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}}$

Comment: I agree with @Isham that you can't pull an index out of a summation.

Comment: Just to be clear, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{x_i}$ is a function of $n$ variables?

Comment: The problem statement is "Show that $\log(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i})$  is a convex function. Write its gradient and Hessian."

Comment: So it is a function of $n$ variables, $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$. That's why you are asked to compute the gradient vector and the Hessian matrix. Also, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[ f(x_i) + g(x_j)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x_i)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65091/discussion-between-dirtysocks45-and-math-lover).